# Problem with Impure Rolling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, rotational-kinematics

Can someone explain what happens in the below situation

**Looking at it from the planks frame of reference:**

The cylinder Velocity= 20(-i)

Net friction force on cylinder f=2umg(i)
(here u=1/2)

**Therefore acceleration of centre of mass of cylinder a= 2ug(i)**

Torque produced by friction: fxr=Ixalpha
(alpha =angular acc.)

**Therefore alpha= (4ug)/r**

**But for rolling wihtout slipping: alpha should be a/r**, which is not the case here

So considering that the cylinder will slip and using standard eq. of motion s=vt+1/at^2 and putting in the values i get a quadratic eq in time whose discriminant is negative.

What went wrong? what is the right approach?

> A solid cylinder is kept on one edge of a plank of same mass and length 25 m placed on a smooth surface as shown i the figure. The coefficient of friction between the cylinder and the plank is 0.5. The plank is given a velocity of 20 m/s towards right. Find the time (in sec) after which plank and cylinder will separate.
>
> [image]

Comment: Try to use math formatting for the equations. Enclose math expressions in dollar signs `$...$` for inline math, and `$$...$$` for paragraph math. See [help/notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for more details.

Comment: Does the cylinder start from rest at the instant the plank is moving at 20 m/s?  This is the implication, but it wasn't stated in the problem.

Comment: yes the cylinder starts from rest

Comment: I'm refunding the bounty on this question because [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: i look froward to the concept to be used here rather than the solution.

Comment: @ACuriousMind i've reworded the question please take of the hold

Comment: Not asking for the full solution does not make the question more on-topic. It is also not clear what you mean by "alpha" and "Accelartionc.o.m/R" is probably misspelled. It might become clearer what conceptual question you're trying to ask if you explain a bit more what you did and why you think the cylinder will (not) roll/slip.

Comment: @ACuriousMind ok i've edited to explain the situation better. please take off the hold at least now. this question is very important!!!

Comment: The explanation *is* much better (although you should still use MathJax as indicated by ja72's comment), but I'm afraid you still just seem to be asking us how to solve this problem correctly (it's also not clear how you arrive at an unsolvable equation just by assuming slipping, but putting that in wouldn't make it any more conceptual). I'm sorry that that kind of question is off-topic here, no matter how important it may be to you personally. We collect sites that may accept such questions [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/50583)

Comment: Did the teacher assume $g=10$, $g=9.81$ or $g=9.80665$?

Comment: Hint: 1) Calculate the angular acceleration and find the time needed for the cylinder to match speed with the plank. 2) Find the distance the plank moves in this time. 3) Find the time needed to move the remaining distance to the end of the plank. Add the times from 1) and 2). If you use $g=10$ the numbers come out nicely.

Comment: should this be done in the ground frame

Comment: assuming ground frame: Vplank=Rw ; 20-ugt=Rαt ; (in ground frame alpha=2ug/R) : 20-ugt=2ugt ; t=20/3ug ; t1= 4/3 . Is this correct